# Java - flow of execution

Tags: java, swing

I am still a newbie and this is more of a curious/wanting to learn question.

I have created a small swing appplication which connects , retrieves data and disconnects from the database. It works fine  and I have no issues.

From the Controller, I call the following methods:

```
   1----> db.connectDB();

   2---->  db.doSomeAction();

   3----> db.disConnectDB();
```

Now, my question is, will method 3 wait until method 2 retrieves the entire result set from the database which is like 1,000,000 records and only after that execute to disconnect from the database?

Method 1, 2 and 3 do not return any thing except they will perform an action. How do I ensure it does not disconnect while  I am still retrieving records from the database.

I am using the SwingUtilities.InvokeLater method to execute my application. Will this scenario still happen?

Comment: Depends entirely on what `db` is, specifically on the behavior of `doSomeAction()`.   Could be synchronous, could be asynchronous.

Comment: @ CPerkins.......I am connecting to an Oracle database and the doSomeAction() retrives the resultset and populates it in a JTable.

Comment: why the down vote? My question is clear and provided all the information....I thought Stackoverlfow is a place to ask "reasonable" questions?????

Comment: You should not use invokeLater() to do a database access. This will freeze the GUI. Use a SwingWorker. Then the DB access code is done on a non GUI Thread. When the DB access is finished you publish the results and then the update to the GUI can be done on the EDT.

Comment: @user547453, you thought wrong. People consistently downvote without providing any reason which is of no value to anybody. Give people a little power...

Comment: Thanks camickr! I have updated my code to run from a Swing Worker thread. Should I also make my 3 methods Synchronized eventhough there is only one Swing Worker thread? And if it is a non swing app, there is no SwingWorker thread and in that case making my methods Synchronized will be helpful? I am wondering there is only one main thread that will be executing and do we still need in this case.

Comment: If the methods access an object from another thread, yes, you need to synchronise, for example accessing a table model. Another approach would be to make the SwingWorker to return a list of database records (not a ResultSet), and then populate the table model. This second approach would save you to synchronise.

Comment: The database query will wait until the query is completed that is why the code should be executed in a separate Thread. There is no need to synchronize. I'm referring to the second approach suggested by Igor. I would just create a new TableModel in the SwingWorker. Then you can publish the model and reset the table with the new model.

Comment: Thanks Igor...I understand your second approach. But I am finding it difficult to understand the first approach.

Comment: @user547453 I did not downvote you. But again, the answer to your question depends on the actual behavior of `doSomething`.  If it's synchronous, then yes, the subsequent call will wait.  If asynchronous, then although the call to disconnect will happen after the call to `doSomething` returns, it may not be after the actual action has completed.

Comment: @CPerkins...no problem. I did not think you did it either. But you are very kind to let me know. And thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the three methods from inside the same thread, their call will be sequential, so method 3 will wait the end of method 2 to start.

Comment: @Igor...even though the methods do not retrun anything?

Comment: @user547453 Yes, there's no difference.